# Create an item and bag handler for a text-based RPG

Tags: java

For practice, I'm creating a text-based RPG using Java. I'm currently using .properties files to handle character info. I understand that YAML might be a better option, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it. Using properties, it would be easy to create an inventory handler (slot1, slot2, etc.), but creating items and reading the slots for item IDs is a little beyond me.

Could I get some assistance?

To further elaborate, I'd like to create a system with three types of items: items to be used on the environment, items to be held in hand (like weapons or shields), and items to be worn.

Comment: what's wrong with comma delimiting item ID's?

Comment: An XML file that describes all of the items might be good

Comment: Please read tag info for meaning on this site before using them.  RPG is a programming language used primarily for business applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try parsing YAML yourself(unless you want to practice parsing, or to write a parsing library). Instead, use a YAML library - you can find some for Java at [the official YAML website](http://yaml.org/)(I don't want to recommend any because I've never done YAML in Java).

Anyways, unless the serialized data needs to be read and edited by hand frequently, I suggest you use JSON. YAML's biggest advantage is it's readability and editability(yea, JSON and XML can be read and edited by humans as well, but not as neatly and elegantly as YAML). If you don't need that advantage, JSON is better because it has excellent, renowned libraries - like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)(From a quick glance, YAML's libraries don't seem nearly as good...)

Whatever you do - don't go with XML.

Comment: Very useful. Suppose I'm using GSON, is there a way to neatly organize different items' data into groups (rather than have a bunch of entries like "item0dmg, item0canUse, etc" but rather "item0: canUse=true dmg=1")? I'm not asking you to write code for me, but a quick example would greatly assist.

Comment: Actually, I believe I've got it. Thank you for your help. JSON is definitely the way to go.